# Send POST request in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, rest, tomcat, google-chrome-extension

**I want to do http POST request in javascript.**

This is Chrome extension background.js file from which I want to send the current tab URL to my Rest Service hosted on Apache tomcat 8.0

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

          chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
          alert(tabs[0].url)
          var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var params = tabs[0].url;
            var someValue = "http://localhost:8080/GetSomeRest/webresources/service/";

            http.open("POST", someValue, true);

            http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
            http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
            http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

            http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                alert(http.responseText);
            }
            http.send(params);
        });
      });
```

My Rest service is working fine as I verified it by using POSTMAN extension. Why is my extension not able to send URL as parameter to java module?

here's my java code snapshot

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.vichargrave;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;


@Path("service")
public class ServiceResource {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    public ServiceResource() {
    }


    @POST
    @Consumes("text/plain")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String postHandler(String content) {
        System.out.print("gre");
        System.out.println(content);
        return content+"chum"+"bj";
    }

}
```

Any hints ?
I can further post the code of my REST service as well as chrome extension if someone asks so for clarity. Thanks

Comment: What happens on the server when you send the `params`?

Comment: Nothing is being triggered, my java module is running succesfully, it seems as if nothing is communicated between REST service and chrome extension

Comment: I had added my java code snapshot

Comment: Where is my System.out.print("gre") is printing? at least not in console for me